# Flutter keep webview state unchanged, When lifecycle onResumed

Tags: webview, state

In my flutter app I have integrated Digilocker aadhar integration, But when I am moving to galley for see aadhar number, Due to the state change soft keyboard getting hide, anyone can help me to keep state same

some solution that I have done.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOnkN.png)

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" or stateUnchanged

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCf11.png)

some solution that I have done.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOnkN.png)

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" or stateUnchanged
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkop5.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)